# Segue performing prematurely in if / else clause

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

The following code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var knock: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

var count: Int = 0
var unlocked: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func knockKnock(sender: UIButton) {

    if count < 20 {
        label.text = "Knocked \(count) times."

    } else if count > 19 && count < 40 {
        label.text = "Knocked \(count) times."
        label.textColor = UIColor.randomColor()

    } else if count > 39 && count < 100 {
        label.text = "That's enough."
        label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    } else if count > 99 && count < 102 {
        label.text = "I wish you hadn't done that."
        label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

    } else if count == 103 {
        label.text = "Fine, come in."
        label.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        count = 126
        unlocked += 1

    }

    if unlocked > 0 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("InsideHomeSegue", sender:sender)
    }

    count += 1

}
```

is prematurely performing the Segue in

```
 if unlocked > 0 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("InsideHomeSegue", sender:sender)
    }
```

The segue is performed immediately the first time the button is pressed, which I do not understand, as at that point the code should be unreachable behind a false `if` statement, since int `unlocked` is initialized with `0`

I have had similar problems which turned out to be issues with XCode itself rather than my code; I have looked through all the files I can find referencing any variables or objects in Interface Builder, checked for naming inconsistencies, rogue outlets, etc.

I still have a very shaky understanding of Segues, and would appreciate any detailed help anyone can offer.

The larger `if` / `else if` block worked properly all the way up to the final increment until Segue code was added. 
Originally the `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("InsideHomeSegue", sender:sender)` line was inside the `else if count == 103 {` block; `var unlocked: Int` was added to combat the Segue issue to no avail.

I've read through several pages of the XCode documentation on Segues, but haven't found anything else I can try.

It's possible I've overlooked something incredibly obvious, but regardless, thanks for reading.

Cheers

**EDIT:** I have checked all outlets, it's the only Segue in the project currently and it isn't hooked up anywhere else. The Segue is activated on a button press, not immediately on View load.

Comment: Are you sure that there's no other entery point for perfoming the segue? like you've connected the segue to you button?

Comment: You need to set your `Segue` with your `ViewController` not with your `Button`, change that and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like what my comment said, You've connected the segue with your button, so that the segue will alway execute. It has nothing to do with `if` clause.

You should connect with the ViewController instead of connecting with a button

Comment: Thanks so much! 

This was pretty basic but I overlooked it, after some tweeking everything seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your two ViewController with a segue, giving it an identifier. Then, you can trigger the segue in this way.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_name_identifier", sender: self)
```

Here how you can easily set your segue.

[image]

I hope that this will help you.